# SSRS Matrix report excluding detail rows where Total Column is under certain dollar amount

Tags: reporting-services

Good Morning. I have a matrix crosstab report in SSRS image below.  I am attempting to hide detail rows where total column which displays grand total for all the years  is less than 100K however for the row grouping totals I need to show the original total i.e. the total that includes the values from the rows I've hidden. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

[image: Report Screen shot]

Comment: Have you already tried setting the `Visibility` property for the row?

Comment: I did and I must not be doing it right. Instead of hiding the lowest level group row  it aggregates the totals so if I have two rows one of 50K and the other of 120K the report shows now aggregated row of 170K without displaying the lowest group label.